# Defer loading CSS added normally in the HTML

Tags: html, css, shopify, pagespeed, deferred-loading

I am optimising a Shopify website for PageSpeed and I am working on "Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content". I optimised CSS delivery of many files using `filamentgroup/loadCSS`. But there are some CSS files added by Shopify and other apps I'm using. As those are added inside the `<head>` and I don't have any control over it, how can I defer loading of those CSS?

Comment: You can  [see here](https://codepen.io/tigt/post/async-css-without-javascript)

Comment: Why should you?

Comment: @ManjeetThakur I could use one of those methods only if I can control adding those CSS files to the HTML. The problem is that some files are added automatically by Shopify and other apps.

Comment: @slynagh https://varvy.com/pagespeed/render-blocking-css.html

Comment: @Debiprasa I think this issue related to #Shopify please verify that how to minify CSS files in [Please see here ](https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-discussion/t/how-i-compress-my-javascript-css-xml-files-for-shopify-27494)